# Python 3 Config Import

Tags: python

apologies if this is an obvious question, but I've been struggling to wrap my head around how to set this up all morning and Google isn't helping.

**Background**

I have a data science project which relies on a couple different custom tools (data-fetching functions, data-processing functions, plotting functions, etc.). Previously they've all just lived in their own files in my project directory, and I've been basically running them as scripts or calling them through `exec`. The code has grown enough that I'd like to pull out some core utilities and put them in a package that lives in my project dir. I'm imagining a project structure like this:

```
project
│   notebook1.ipynb
│   notebook2.ipynb
│
└───project_utilities
    │   __init__.py
    │   config.py
    │   get_data.py
    |   transform_data.py
    |   common_plots.py
```

So that in my reporting notebooks I can just call an `import project_utilities as pu` and have access to all my handy functions (among other things).

**The Problem**

I'm getting really turned around when it comes to sharing variables between my modules. Following the recommendation of the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules) I'm creating a `config.py` file where I place all my global variables, which I am trying to use as follows:

```
# config.py
DATA_DIR = "~/project/data"

# get_data.py
import pandas as pd
import config

def get_data():
    return(pd.read_csv(config.DATA_DIR + 'dat.csv'))
```

But when I go to `import project_utilities.get_data` I get an error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config`

Now, I have figured out a workaround using relative paths:

```
# get_data.py
import pandas as pd
from .config import *

def get_data():
    return(pd.read_csv(config.DATA_DIR))
```

But since this isn't consistent with the docs' recommendation I'm worried it's not pythonic or something. It's really driving me crazy, am I missing something obvious, or is this just an oversight on the part of the FAQ? And if so, what's a better source to refer to in the future?

Comment: `from . import config`

Comment: Gotcha, is that the "correct" way to handle intra-package imports in general? @JohnGordon

Comment: Yes, that's the "most pythonic" way to do it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks John!